# Layout Overlapping Issue Between React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

```
import React from 'react';
import ServiceItem from '../components/ServiceItem';
import { services } from '../utils/services';
import { SERVICE_BG_IMG } from '../config/constants';

function Service() {
    return (
        <div className='w-full relative'>
            <div className='w-full bg-cover bg-center h-[500px]' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${SERVICE_BG_IMG})` }} >
                <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-custom-blue opacity-80"></div>
            </div>
            <div className='absolute top-20 w-full'>
                <div className='w-full flex justify-center items-center px-3'>
                    <h1 className='text-center text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl text-white font-semibold'>Our most popular <br /> <span className='text-custom-green'>services for you</span></h1>
                </div>
                <div className='w-full flex justify-center mt-10'>
                    <div className='w-5/6 grid grid-cols-1 place-items-center gap-8 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3'>
                        {services.slice(0, 8).map((item, index) => (
                            <ServiceItem key={item.title} title={item.title} description={item.description} url={item.url} redirect_path={item.redirect_path} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Service;
```

I attempted to resolve the layout overlapping issue by adjusting the positioning and styling within the `Service` component in my React application. I expected the subsequent component to be positioned below the `Service` component without any overlapping. However, despite my efforts, the problem persists, and I am seeking further assistance to identify and address the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the CSS are messed up. I am not a fan of Tailwind, but `absolute` is the one that is making the trouble.

You can try

- Adding vertical offset relative to the `Service component`
- Hope there are no other CSS properties with higher specificity
- Try to add margins / paddings to `Service Component`

If Possible, it would be nice to share your code in codepen